# Get All Applied Promotions

Tags: magento

So Magento groups promotions together on the shopping cart page. I'd like to break them apart and show the individual promos that are being applied. I am having a really hard time though figuring out how to get a list of just applied promotions.

Answer (score 3):

Figured... looked all over for the answer and as soon as I post a question here I find the answer... anyway here it is

```
$quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();    
$quote->getAppliedRuleIds()
```